# Android - Make custom view's transparent area not clickable

Tags: java, android, android-view

I have an custom view that has a circular shape.

[image: custom view that has a circle]

the circle has a touch listener, which will shows an animation when it is touched.
(i will use a red spot for reference.)

[image: responds view when it is touched]

but the problem is, when I touch ouside the circle, the animation is shown, which is useless.

[image: when it is touched outside]

so, my question is, **can I make this view touchable inside the circle?**

Comment: it should be, if the touched coordinates are inside the dimensions of the view. Or does the view fill the whole screen?

Comment: yeah, it should be. But now I want to make it touchable inside the circle, neither inside the dimensions nor the whole screen.

Comment: yes I understand, what I mean is, that You can limit the touch event. If You check the coordinates where the touch is registered, You can say for exampl, if(x>200) -> do nothing, else do your stuff...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the touch event in your view and check whether or not its distance from the center of the circle is less then its radius.

This needs to be done like this, because views on Android are basically always rectangular.

Comment: this idea made view clickable inside the circle, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is a bit late, but it might help someone, who is looking for an answer :

- First: inherit from ImageView as following:

  ```
  public class CustomImageView extends ImageView implements View.OnTouchListener {



   private Bitmap bitmap;

   private OnClickListener listener;

   private boolean clicking;


   private int pressedColor;



   public CustomImageView(Context context) {

    super(context);

    init();

   }



   public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

    super(context, attrs);

    init();

   }



   public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {

    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

    init();

   }



   @Override

   public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener l) {

    listener = l;

    setOnTouchListener(this);

   }



   @Override

   public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

    if (isInClickArea(motionEvent)) {

     if (motionEvent.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

      clicking = true;

      setColorFilter(pressedColor, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

     } else if (motionEvent.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

      if (clicking) {

       clicking = false;

       setColorFilter(null);

       listener.onClick(view);

      }

     }

     return true;

    }

    clicking = false;

    setColorFilter(null);



    return false;

   }



   private boolean isInClickArea(MotionEvent event) {

    int clickX = (int)(event.getX() * ((double) bitmap.getWidth() / (double) getWidth()));

    int clickY = (int)(event.getY() * ((double) bitmap.getHeight() / (double) getHeight()));

    if (bitmap != null) {

     if (clickX >= 0 && clickX < bitmap.getWidth() && clickY >= 0 && clickY < bitmap.getHeight()) {

      if (Color.alpha(bitmap.getPixel(clickX, clickY)) > 0) {

       return true;

      }

     }

    }

    return false;

   }



   private void init() {

    int color = (int)(255 * 0.96 f);

    pressedColor = Color.rgb(color, color, color);

    Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

    if (drawable != null) {

     if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {

      bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();

     } else if (drawable instanceof LayerDrawable) {

      bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(128, 128, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

      drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 128, 128);

      drawable.draw(new Canvas(bitmap));

     }

    }

   }



  }
  ```
- Second: set an ImageView in the layout :

  ```
  <FrameLayout
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  >
      <com.myapp.custom.CustomImageView 
        android:id="@+id/button_id"
        android:src="@drawable/image_with_transparent_area"
       .../>
  ```

And now it should work as you want .

PS: You can use transparent image or create your own shape with xml file within drawables and then use src normaly to import your shape .

Happy coding :)

Comment: Tnx, helped alot! :)

Answer (score -1):

Yes we can make particular view touchable/clickable in the screen. Your main screen will be within layout and circle will be part of it as view. While launching the application setcontentView will inflate the layout and your main layout will be parent of all other view. We can get the view by using the finviewByID and we can implement touchListner/clickListner to this view not to full screen/layout. This will solve your problem.

Comment: you gave a little approach to the answer. but it isn't solve my problem. Like in the previous answer, views are basically rectangular. but my view is circular, within a rectangular view layout (actually, a view cage). thank you for your answer, but it is not the solutution for me.